# Check the version of database when a table was created in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there a way to check the version of the database when a table was created?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *the version of the database* The term not exists. There exists the version of DBMS - do you need in it? Or maybe you need in the database revision version from the application looking point? in this case you'd store such data in the service table created in your database.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. MySQL does not track the version of software when the table was created.

The metadata for a table can be viewed with the command [SHOW TABLE STATUS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/show-table-status.html). One of the fields is labeled VERSION, but it's not the version of MySQL Server, it's the version of the ".frm" file format, which was a file to store metadata about the table. It was version 10 in MySQL 5.7, but in MySQL 8.0 they no longer use .frm files, so the value will be fixed at "10" forever.

Out of curiosity, why do you need to know this?

Comment: Thanks @Bill Karwin. I wanted to know w.r.t:               
Tables created before MySQL 5.6 that include temporal columns (DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP) and have not been rebuilt using ALGORITHM=COPY do not support ALGORITHM=INPLACE. In this case, an ALTER TABLE ...

Comment: If in doubt, I would run `ALTER TABLE <name> FORCE` to make sure the table has been rebuilt after the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Karwin. Also for a big table, altering the same to add or modify column, what do you suggest?

Comment: I use [pt-online-schema-change](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html).

Comment: can the pt-online-schema-change run a consolidated sql script?

Comment: That tool only runs one ALTER TABLE statement at a time. It's up to you to invoke it with the right arguments.